# List of controls in code behind

Tags: asp.net

How can I add to a list<> some controls of my dashboard? I do something like `List<String> NewList = new List<Strings>(){}` but this throw me errors

I'm trying to add some linkButtons into the list.

I'm tying to do something like this but is wrong

```
protected void listLink(){
            List<LinkButton> linksList = new List<LinkButton>();
            listLink{

            }
        }
```

I want to use that list in other events

my `linkbuttons` are in `visible = false;`

Comment: not enough detail here to help. You haven't said exactly what you've added this object to ("dashboard" could mean almost anything), in what context, what you wanted to achieve by it, or what errors you got.

Comment: @ADyson I edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand you want to create a list of LinkButtons using [Object Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) way.

Below code snippet should help you.
**Aspx code:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn1" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn2" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
</form>
```

**Aspx.cs code:**

```
List<LinkButton> lnkBtnCollection = null;

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Object Initialization way
        lnkBtnCollection = new List<LinkButton>
        {
            lnkBtn1, lnkBtn2
        };

        //Second way  where items are added to the list after the list is created
        //lnkBtnCollection = new List<LinkButton>();
        //lnkBtnCollection.Add(lnkBtn1);
        //lnkBtnCollection.Add(lnkBtn2);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Use LinkBtn Collection here 
       foreach (var lnkBtn in lnkBtnCollection)
       {

       }
    }
```